# How to Update Swift Version Dynamic Coca Touch Framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift-framework

I Created a dynamic framework on Swift 3.2 & Xcode 9.0  and use it in my projects worked fine, 
today, I update to Xcode 9.2 & Swift 4.0 so compiled framework on Swift 4.0 and export `myFramework.framework` so added by `embedded Binaries` it in project.
This is a strange problem when add new framework with Swift 4.0 not resolve any Framework Classes and get error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'MyClassName'

I tired more solution but no solved my problem.

Note: All of Classes Framework have **open** access.

Where my Framework Problem?

Is there an easy way to update framework swift version?

Comment: try to put your framework under the project root folder, that contain viewcontrollers

Comment: @chawki I did the same

Comment: Did you tried to read those steps to Embed your framework : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2435/_index.html

Comment: @chawki thanks but Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue was that I build framework via `Generic iOS Device` If it should compiled on iOS Simulators like iPhone SE or iPhone 8.
I build framework on one of `iOS Simulator Device` and import in project.